# Remove single quote characters from specific field inside JSON data

Tags: c#, regex

I have this json data string below, which I need to do some cleaning before I can Deserialize into an object in C#.  Here's my json string:

```
{'data':[
    {'ID':'01','Name':'Name 1','Description':'abc','Skills':[{'Type':'abc','Technical':'abc','Description':'abc'}],'Status':false,'Inactive':0},
    {'ID':'02','Name':'Name 2','Description':'abc','Skills':[{'Type':'abc','Technical':'abc','Description':'abc'}],'Status':false,'Inactive':0},
    {'ID':'03','Name':'Name 3','Description':'abc','Skills':[{'Type':'abc','Technical':'abc','Description':'abc'}],'Status':false,'Inactive':1}]}
```

What I'm trying to do is REMOVE single quote (') character from the following field in the above data:

```
'Skills':[{'Type':'abc','Technical':'abc','Description':'abc'}]
```

So what I need to achieve is to have "Skills" field to look like this:

```
'Skills':[{Type:abc,Technical:abc,Description:abc}]
```

I designed this Regex patter:

```
(?<='Skills':\[\{)(.*?)(?=\}\],)
```

It matches the string below, but I don't know how to exclude single quotes.

```
'Type':'abc','Technical':'abc','Description':'abc'
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: That's not valid json - where is this json being produced? Can it be created correctly then you won't have to do any cleaning.

Comment: Removing the single quotes everywhere doesn't produce valid JSON either, since strings must be enclosed in double quotes. You'd be better off replacing single quotes with double quotes (but you'd also have to escape any double quotes already there). Something like `.Replace("\"", "\\\"" ).Replace("'","\"")`

Comment: But of course, fixing it at the source is a much more bulletproof solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify json data.  It is what it is.  It comes from outside and I need to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to modify the source to get pretty formatted JSON, it's not standard JSON format.

if you don't have access to modify the source output, you can use this :

```
        string content = Console.ReadLine();

        var matchResult = new Regex("(?<='Skills':).*?}]").Matches(content);

        foreach(Match match in matchResult)
        {
            string matchValueWithoutSingleQuote = match.Value.Replace("'", string.Empty);
            content = content.Replace(match.Value, matchValueWithoutSingleQuote);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(content);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

the output is :

```
{'data':[
    {'ID':'01','Name':'Name 1','Description':'abc','Skills':[{Type:abc,Technical:abc,Description:abc}],'Status':false,'Inactive':0},
    {'ID':'02','Name':'Name 2','Description':'abc','Skills':[{Type:abc,Technical:abc,Description:abc}],'Status':false,'Inactive':0},
    {'ID':'03','Name':'Name 3','Description':'abc','Skills':[{Type:abc,Technical:abc,Description:abc}],'Status':false,'Inactive':1}]}
```

Linq version :

```
string content = Console.ReadLine();

var matchResult = new Regex("(?<='Skills':).*?}]").Matches(content);

var jsonWithNormalizedSkillField = matchResult.Cast<Match>().Select(s => content.Replace(s.Value, s.Value.Replace("'", string.Empty))).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(jsonWithNormalizedSkillField);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, source cannot be modified.  It comes from outside and needs to stay the way it is.  All I want is to be able to remove Single Quote character from within the "Skills:[{...}]" field not touching any other field.

One more thing I just realized is that fields within Skills field could vary, therefore I'd rather stay away from defining filed names inside Skills field.

Comment: Your example doesn't work.  You only tried it for a single record.  Try it for multiple.  Your example returns only string inside Skills field.  I need to have everything returned excluding single quotes inside only every Skills field keeping quotes everywhere else.

Comment: @idelin but the output of the code is same as what you want.

Comment: No, it's not what I want.  Your code above works because you only have data for field Skills inside Content string.  Try putting entire json data in there and it will stop working.

Comment: Oh wow, so looping is unavoidable.  Thank you so much!  It's working for me.

Comment: @idelin You can do it using Linq instead of loop but at the underlying layer in this scenario they are the same. maybe it's clear than loop version.